# MongoDB count items in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say we have a collection as follows

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "sizes": [ "S", "M", "L"] },
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "EFG", "sizes": [ "S" ] },
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "ABC", "sizes": [ "M" ] }
```

How can we list the items in the array (sizes) and the quantity of items associated to the sizes

For example

```
size 'S', item 'ABC' = 1
size 'S', item 'EFG' = 1
size 'M', item 'ABC' = 2
size 'L', item 'ABC' = 1
```

Note that size 'M' has to instances where item is 'ABC'.

I tried the following

```
db.collection.group(
{
    key: {'sizes': true}, 
    initial: {sum: 0}, 
    reduce: function(doc, prev) { prev.sum += 1}
});
```

but it doesn't unwind the array and I can not seem to able to add the Item as part of the group count

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the "sizes" array then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by "item" and "sizes" and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to return the count.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$unwind": "$sizes" }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": { 
                "item": "$item", 
                "sizes": "$sizes" 
            }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
        }}
    ]
)
```

which produces:

```
{ "_id" : { "item" : "EFG", "sizes" : "S" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "item" : "ABC", "sizes" : "L" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "item" : "ABC", "sizes" : "M" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "item" : "ABC", "sizes" : "S" }, "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I was a bit puzzled on how to get the $unwind to work. This is great!!